# Why have hand-crafted invasion stripes and arm bands been used in recent conflicts in addition to the usual military insignia?

Tags: military, uniform, tanks, symbols

Simple and vivid symbols on military vehicles are known as [invasion stripes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_stripes) since at least as early as World War II, when they were invented because the sheer numbers of the invading force might have saturated the normal friend-or-foe identification protocols. The Allies thus must have decided to trade some camouflage for some better identifiability.

Since then, invasion stripes have seen a wider use, from the Cold war conflicts to [the Soviet invasion of Czechoslovakia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_Pact#/media/File:Praga_11.jpg), to [the current war in Ukraine](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/71601). In the latter, troopers are wearing colored bands on their arms or helmets, which probably serve the same purpose as invasion stripes but for individual soldiers.

However, the same tradeoff between being identifiable by one's allies and being less visible for one's enemy has to be considered when designing the normal insignia for the soldiers' uniforms and the vehicles. The Normandy landings may well have been reasonable circumstances for shifting that tradeoff temporarily, but in more recent conflicts the hand-crafted insignia are often worn throughout the entire conflict. Why did these insignia have to be hand-crafted rather than incorporated into the design earlier?

Comment: While the question is interesting, it is about "recent conflicts", which strongly suggests it is off-topic for *History* Stackexchange. Consider a re-write that focuses on historical aspects.

Comment: Not a history answer so a comment but suspect as a nation there are PR issues with 'welcome to the army, we keep shooting you infantry guys by mistake so have added high visibility markings to your uniforms so more of you die by enemy fire rather than our own'.

Comment: An interesting note, @GremlinWranger, which makes one wonder whether arm bands are used in other armies except Russia and its close neighbours like Ukraine (who probably use mostly the same, Russian-manufactured, uniforms and vehicles, thus requiring additional visibility). This, however, would be another question.

Comment: The standard Russian camo uniforms (darker green for warmer months, more beige-ish for colder months) do fade to look a lot like the standard Ukrainian uniform - it seems that identification from even a middle distance (1-200 meters, where most contact is made) would be a problem. This is especially true if both sides are using a lot of the same equipment and firearms, so other visual and audio cues are absent. And parts of this war have been small units, so there are also not the cues of "The bad guys' front line is over there 200 meters".)

Comment: Just a guess, but if you try the more in advance you try to do things like that, the more probable is that the secret spills back to the enemy, rendering the effort useless.

Comment: @SJuan76, why should the design of invasion stripes and arm bands be kept in secret? Standard insignia aren't, and dressing as enemy is easily possible but rarely performed, because generally, both sides are interested in correct identification.